# Conversion failed - nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sqlexception

I have following sql stored procedure, but the c# code catches the exception with following message:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int
```

SQL Stored procedure

```
@byTestType int
AS
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(3000)
IF @byTestType = 4
BEGIN
    SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM aTbl ORDER BY aCol'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM aTbl WHERE aCol= '
    SET @qry = @qry +''''+CAST(@byTestType as varchar(3))+''''
END

EXEC sp_executesql @qry
```

aCol datatype is varchar(3)

don't understand what is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and modified you demo a bit

```
DECLARE @byTestType int = 1200

DECLARE @qry nvarchar(3000)

IF @byTestType = 4
BEGIN
    SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM aTbl ORDER BY aCol'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM aTbl WHERE aCol= '
    SET @qry = @qry +''''+CAST(@byTestType as varchar(3))+''''
END

print @qry
```

the funny thing is that the output is:

> SELECT * FROM aTbl WHERE aCol= '*'

please modify your row

```
 SET @qry = @qry +''''+CAST(@byTestType as nvarchar)+''''
```

please also take care of the following situation

```
DECLARE @byTestType int = NULL
```

in this case your @qry will be NULL